# Is there any way to work with vtypes on a editorgridpanel

Tags: extjs

I'm working on a editorGridPanel and I need to validate that a column can get only numeric values. It's just that every sample I can get I see working on Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, etc..) but is those cases is for working with formPanel.

Answer (score 0):

The editor object of the column allows for validation. I understand that the editor field behaves like a form field. I didn't find yet a difference. I would try :

```
columns: [{
    header: ..., 
    dataIndex: ..., 
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield', 
        vtypes: ...
```